# eloquent sql query that group all column with similar values and get similar results respected to every group

Tags: mysql, sql, select, eloquent

Hi I have a long table with two columns: 1.region 2.subregion Like below:

```
region  | subregion
  1     |     3
  1     |     7
  2     |     8
  1     |     1
```

I want results like this:

```
region  | subregion
  1     |     3,7,1
  2     |     8
```

is it possible with simple select query?

Comment: Hint:  `group_concat()`.

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`select region,group_concat(subregion) from MyTable group by region`